# 100 Amp Sub Panel in basement garage from 200 Amp Main in the upstairs garage

Tags: subpanel

I have a two story garage. The bottom garage is below grade on 3 sides. The upstairs garage has its own 200 AMP main service. I will be running wire from the main via 100 amp breaker to the sub panel that will also have a 100 amp breaker. I am not exactly sure what the best wire for this run should be 2-2-2-4? This run is about 25 feet. This run will be in the wall (through 2x4 studs) in the upstairs garage to the exit whole then into conduit as it goes down the exterior wall and through the masonry wall into the downstairs garage. 
Here are my questions.
1. What is the best wire for this project?
2. Does this wire need to be in conduit for the entire run or just where it goes through the exterior of the building and while it is outside? The main and sub are both inside and this run doesn't go underground. It just goes down the side of the garage.
3. What size conduit and type? 
3. Will I need to add another ground rod at the sub-panel? (Of course the sub-panel will not be bonded. Isolated grounds and neutrals.)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Would you be willing to use conduit, assuming you won't have to face the difficulty of shoving a bulky stiff cable up the conduit? (we'll use much more flexible wires).

Comment: Are the existing and new panel locations on exterior or interior walls?

Comment: You can use any subpanel >=100A, and it doesn't need a main breaker unless it's in a different building.  In fact a 100A subpanel is a bad idea, because it'll have too few spaces, leading to running out of spaces quickly.

Comment: You leave a little too much to the imagination to get good should/could answers. Generally I would run SER #3 CU or # 1 AL in the 2x4's, splice to THWN conductors in a 10x10 J-box before leaving the building in 1.25" PVC (maybe a 6x6 and 1" if CU), that I would try to run all the way into the new panel. No additional ground rods should be required at the new panel within the same building. There might be ways I would want to or need to do it different if I was giving my opinion from in the garage.

Comment: Would you be willing to use conduit, assuming you won't have to face the difficulty of shoving a bulky stiff cable up the conduit? (we'll use much more flexible wires). – Harper - Reinstate Monica Nov 22 at 22:21                                          I will use conduit through the walls, and into the sub panel.

Comment: Are the existing and new panel locations on exterior or interior walls? – ThreePhaseEel Nov 23 at 0:38                                                                                              Both panels are located inside. Because of the cement floor,  12"  of cement, the main wire will need to run from the main panel through the interior studs, over a door, down a stud, through more studs and then out of the wall through conduit down 6 feet and than into the lower wall and finally the sub panel located inside.

Comment: I am thinking of using 2" conduit just to make life easier. the wire will make a 90 deg. out into a 90 deg. box going down into another 90 degree box and into the lower garage and finally another 90 into the  sub panel.